# How to get unmounted device from Ansible facts

Tags: linux, ansible

I would like to implement such demands via Ansible playbook
1. Get Ansible host facts
2. Run through "ansible_mounts.device" using ansible_device
3. If any device is not in ansible.mounts.device then print them into a file.

Below is my playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: list all mounted device
    shell: /bin/echo {{ item.device }} >> /root/mounted
    with_items: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
    register: mounted_device
  - name: list all umount disks
    shell: /bin/echo {{ item }}
    with_items: "{{ ansible_devices.keys() }}"
    when: '{{ item }} not in {{ mounted_device }} '
```

However, the mounted_device is always a list of all information in ansible_mounts element which I thought it should be list of devices like "/dev/xvda1". Actually, in /root/mounted it *is* "/dev/xvda1"

Can anyone please help with this? Or is there any more brilliant way to achieve the goal?

Comment: The first task is not going to behave the way I think you expect. 'register' will store the output of the task + information about the task. In this case, you are running the shell command several times and simply echoing a value into a file. That produces no output. So because your shell command is running several times, 'mounted_device' will contain a list of info, with each element representing one invocation. Could you describe what is the actual thing you are looking to achieve (i.e. why you are trying to produce this list)?

Comment: Because I am planning to do a autoscaling on AWS so there will be a new node from time to time. To make this new node available, I need to mount a EBS to it. However,the EBS device name might be random with prefix xvd, e.g. xvdf,xvdg. So that I need first get the device name of the EBS , then mount it. This playbook is to filter the unmount device out from ansible_mounts which contains all mounted partition/device.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you could get something to work using the approach you are taking, I would not recommend it as it will be complicated and fragile.

AWS provides a special API endpoint that will expose information about your running instance. This endpoint is accessible (from your running instance) at http://169.254.169.254.

Information about block devices is located at  http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ which will give you a list of block devices. The primary block device is named 'ami', and then any subsequent EBS volumes are named 'ebs2', 'ebs3', ..., 'ebsn'. You can then visit http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ebs2 which will simply return the OS device name mapped to that block device (i.e. 'sdb').

Taking this info, here is some example code to access the data for the 1st additional EBS volume:

```
- name: Set EBS name to query
  set_fact:
    ebs_volume: ebs2
- name: Get device mapping data
  uri:
    url: "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/{{ ebs_volume }}"
    return_content: yes
  register: ebs_volume_data
- name: Display returned data
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ebs_volume_data.content }}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try with this solution asap. :)

Comment: unfortunately this solution does not work with nvme instances